# Referential Data Integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing work on Referential Data Integrity in sql.

I want to create a scenario that i have three tables name `branch1`, `branch2` and `branch3`. `Branch2` and `Branch3` are join with `branch1` table with foreign key.

now i want to create a system on `branch1` table if i insert 'active' in `branch1` table the `branch2` and `branch3` table will able to insert in the table and when i insert 'inactive' in `branch1` table the other 2 tables will not be able to insert any thing in the table.

this all thing want to create with Referential Data Integrity.

So Please help me i have tried but i didn't successful

Comment: What you are describing has nothing to do with referential integrity (at least not with how foreign keys actually work). This is more something that describes application semantics.

Comment: i am talking about cascade update and delete,it is possible to do this with these cascade update and delete.

Comment: This question is not clearly asked. What does the following statement mean? `.. the other 2 tables will not be able to insert any thing in the table.`   Tables don't insert into other tables.  Do you mean, the other two tables become read-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triggers.

A trigger on `BRANCH2` and `BRANCH3` can be used to check for `ACTIVE` in your `BRANCH1` table.  If it exists, the insert can continue, if not, the insert can be cancelled.

Refer to [MSDN Create Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) doco for syntax.

Here's a tutorial I found off a quick google: [An Intro to SQL Triggers @ SQL Team](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)

---

If you also need to control referential integrity, triggers can be used for this too - eg if a parent record is deleted from one table, a trigger on that table can delete child records from other tables first, to ensure constraints don't block the delete.

However as there's no real parent/child relationship described in your question, I can't see how referential integrity applies.

Comment: OK BUT I WANT THESE TO DO WITH CASCADE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY

Comment: @Mufasil What you've described in your question has nothing to do with cascading referential integrity.  Your question describes controlling inserts on `BRANCH2` and `BRANCH3` based on values in `BRANCH1`.

Comment: ok but someone say me to do with cascading referential integrity.Can you tell me it is possible to do with it.

Comment: @Mufusil these use triggers too.  Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx.  But I still don't see how these relate to your scenario, as asked in your question.

Comment: @Mufasil: It's not possible to do what you described using foreign keys with ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE.

Answer (score 0):

Tables do not insert data into other tables. Queries do. You can always add a 'where' clause in the queries to make the updates conditional.

Comment: yes exactly,but i want that if i create these three table i want to create cascade method in branch1 table if i insert 'active' by query in table branch1 then i insert into other 2 tables the insert will not perform.